# Adding custom login id and password while creating DSN ODBC connections remotely

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, odbc, registry

I have written a code that can create ODBC DSN Connections remotely. I am able to add registry entries to ODBC.INI. The connections show up in The ODBC Data Source Administrator.

What I am struggling with is that when I choose SQL Server authentication using a login ID and password entered by the user. By default it takes up the user which runs the program while I want it to be decided by the user while running the code. All other entries are entered by the user.

[image]

How should I go about achieving this? I tried adding attributes to the registry entries, but that did not seem to work.

This is a section of my code that basically adds the registry key.

```
 string reg_location = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI";
            dsn_name = reg_location + "\\" + dsn_name;
            RegistryKey Key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, destination_server).CreateSubKey(dsn_name);
            using (Key)
            {
                Key.SetValue("Database", database);
                Key.SetValue("Description", description);
                Key.SetValue("Driver", driver);
                Key.SetValue("Server", server);
                if (trusted_connection.ToLower().Equals("yes") || trusted_connection.ToLower().Equals("true") || trusted_connection.ToLower().Equals("sspi"))
                    Key.SetValue("Trusted_Connection", trusted_connection);
                else if (trusted_connection.ToLower().Equals("false") || trusted_connection.ToLower().Equals("no"))
                {
                    Key.SetValue("User Id", ss_username.Text);
                    Key.SetValue("Password ", ss_password.Text);
                }
                Key.SetValue("LastUser", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
            }
```

Comment: Have you figured this out? If I set Trusted Connection = False I can use any user/pass combination in Excel VBA. But it would be nice to have that saved in the registry.

Comment: The switch is working fine between SQL Server Authentication and Windows Authentication(adding Integrated Security to false), but I have not been to figure out where to store the username and password.